ADF dataflow derived column name issue
I am new to Azure Data Factory, Trying to create some derived columns for a data transformations. In that I want to create a column name as follows 'test:by:uat:trans:schemas:ext:value:2.0:Account' but how it's coming in after the transformation (json) is '0:Account'.
Is there any fix for it.

The above issue might arise when you run the dataflow with auto mapping set to disabled in the sink of the dataflow.
I have created the same column in the dataflow and given some value.

I have created another column name Rakesh.col1 in another derived column.
When you disabled the Auto mapping, it will take the values from the . in your column name. It's due to . is considered as hierarchy or parent in terms of key names. So, it automatically, cuts it from the . sets the name after that as column name. If you run the dataflow like this from the pipeline, the result JSON will contain these column names only.

To avoid, Enable the Auto mapping in the dataflow sink mapping. Now, you can see the output column names as same as input column names in the inspect section of the sink.

It will give the expected results, when you debugged the dataflow from the pipeline.

